# How to return a single value from a function from MySQL to PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, function, return

I've been struggline with this for a while now. I am simply not able to return a single value. I can return arrays just fine. 
But not a single value. I have a database with just three columns, column1 is userID, column2 is friendID and column3 is IfFriends, which has the value 0 or 1.

Now if I make the following function:

```
function CheckFriend($id, $friendid){
global $mysqli;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT IfFriends FROM friends WHERE userID=?
                          AND friendID=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $friendid);
$stmt->bind_result($IfFriends);
$stmt->execute();

    return $IfFriends;
```

Now am I doing it wrong? I tried the SQL query and it works, it gives me back the 1. However if I use the function it gives me back 0.

In PHP I have it written like this:

> $iffriends = CheckFriend($_SESSION["id"], $_REQUEST["friendid"]);

And when I do:

> echo $iffriends

It always gives me back a 0, no matter what.

I hope someone is able to take the time and tell me what I am doing wrong. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php):

> Note:
>
> Note that all columns must be bound after mysqli_stmt_execute() and
>   prior to calling mysqli_stmt_fetch(). Depending on column types bound
>   variables can silently change to the corresponding PHP type.

So your call to `bind` has to be after the `execute` and you will need to call `fetch` to read the first row.

```
// Parameters bound before execute
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $friendid);

// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();

// Result location bound (but this doesn't retrieve anything)
$stmt->bind_result($IfFriends);

// Fetch the first row of the result, stored into the result variable bound above
if($stmt->fetch())
{
  // Make sure you check the result of fetch().
  // If it returned false, no rows were returned.
  // In this case, it returned true, so your value is in $IfFriends
}

// If you happened to have multiple rows, you would call fetch again
// to retrieve the next row.
if($stmt->fetch())
{
  // You can continue calling fetch() until it returns false.
  // Most often this is done in a loop like:
  // while($stmt->fetch()) { /* Do something with the row */ }
}
```

Comment: I actually read that numerous times. Having difficulty understanding it. But I'll figure it out, at least now I know the answer is in there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I kept using arrays before this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for retrieve value. This is a PHP Function. You just call it with a query which has a query of single return value.

```
function value_return($query){

$result= mysql_query($query);
$value=mysql_result($result,0);
return $value;

}
```